# Getting suggestion for people on typing in textbox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, user-profile

I want to build a technique in which if users start typing some name into textbox, then they should be able to get suggestion for matching people's name as drop down list. The names are assumed to be in the profile database. How i do this ? Any suggestion or Good example will be appreciated ?